# How can I downgrade from Plesk 9 to Plesk 8.3?

Tags: web-server, downgrade

I just upgraded my webserver from Plesk 8.3 to Plesk 9. Now it's asking me for a new licence key I don't have! I'd like to come back to the old version, but my last backup doesn't work. What shall I do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your license key to 9.x.

Even if there is a way to downgrade Plesk (and I really doubt it given the amount of changes between 8.x and 9.x), I wouldn't trust it not to completely break your box (not that installing Plesk hasn't already done this for you anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Plesk License Update System](https://register.parallels.com/key_upgrade/). From here you should be able to upgrade the licnese key to the version that you need for the software that is installed.